# How to redirect with variables in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, redirect, django-views

How to redirect with variables in django?
Please guide me, thank you.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^computer/$', views.computer, name='computer'),
    url(r'^result/$', views.result, name='result'),
)
```

This is my original views.py :

```
def computer(request):
    result =  Computer.objects.order_by('?')[:1]
    return render(request, 'many/result.html',{'result':result})
```

And I found I problem, render will not redirect to  `moneymany/result.html` on the url,
so if the user refresh, it will get another result on the same page.

So I have to use redirect to `many/result.html` .
What's the usually way to redirect in django and I have to pass variable `result`?
I try this,but not work :

```
def result(request):
    return render(request, 'many/result.html')

def computer(request):
    result =  Computer.objects.order_by('?')[:1]     
    url = reverse(('many:result'), kwargs={ 'result': result })
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Answer (score 6):

you need

```
url(r'^result/(?P<result>[^\/]*)/$', views.result, name='result'),
```

and

```
return redirect(reverse('many:result', kwargs={ 'result': result }))
```

---

or (without changing url)

```
return redirect('/result/?p=%s' % result )
```

if you want to maintain POST data while redirecting, then it means your design isnot good. quoting Lukasz:

> If you faced such problem there's slight chance that you had
>   over-complicated your design. This is a restriction of HTTP that POST
>   data cannot go with redirects.

Answer (score 4):

How about using redirect.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def computer(request):
    result =  Computer.objects.order_by('?')[:1]
    return redirect('view-name-you-want', { 'result'=result })
```

Comment: there is error````'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 ````

Comment: it's really not me!!! Do you know how to solve the error ````'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 ```` ?

Comment: That's kind of a new question. Somewhere you have a character out of the ASCII range but try to treat it as an ASCII character. Where do you get this error?

Comment: The `=` would need to be a colon because you're passing a dictionary. Also, how would you access the result in the target view?

Comment: It's not { 'result'=result } but { 'result':result }

Answer (score 2):

this worked with i just needed to pass url parameters as arguments

```
return redirect('pagename' ,param1 , param2)
```

my url looks like :

```
path('page', views.somefunction, name="pagename")
```

Note: in my case somefunction accept only POST parameters

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from a view to another view with data, you can use **session** with **request.session['key']** and in this case, you don't need to modify **path()** in **"myapp/urls.py"** as shown below. Then, give **the conbination of the app name "myapp", colon ":" and the view name "dest_view" which is set in path() in "myapp/urls.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_view(request):
    # Here
    request.session['person'] = {'name': 'John', 'age': 27}
                    # Here
    return redirect("myapp:dest_view")
```

```py
# "myapp/urls.py" 

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "myapp"

urlpatterns = [                           # This is view name
    path('dest/', views.destination_view, name="dest_view")
]
```

Then, this is how you get **the data of "post" method**:

```py
# "myapp/index.html"

{{ request.session.person.name }} {# John #}
{{ request.session.person.age }}  {# 27 #}
```